# When to use export vs export default?

Tags: javascript

After skimming through a project on GitHub, it seem to me that `export` and `export default` are used exchangeably. I also aware that when `export default` is used, the bracket is omitted. I'm wondering if there any other difference usage between the two keywords? maybe efficiency? or coding convention?

As far as I know for:
`export`:

```
export function Directive () {}
```

To import the constructor, we do need to put `{ }` for the constructor name:

```
import { Directive } from './someDir'
```

Instead for `export default`, we do not need `{ }`.. i.e:

```
import Directive from './someDir'
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34781258/what-technical-purpose-does-export-default-serve.

Comment: `export default` is used for default exports (of which there can obviously be just one). Named exports are used for named exports, of which there can be many. Which to use (or both) and how to use them is a design decision.